# How to Automate web api testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-api-testing

I want to automate web api testing, but I am a beginner to automation. I have list of REST API's which I want to automate. Can someone please suggest from where should I start? Can I use Selenium to automate?

Comment: You can create test cases in postman(chrome app).

Comment: @Jay How to do that? Do you have any wiki for it?

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda I have added answer below. check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can write test cases with postman and test all your web apis.

Like test response time, status code, content-type and much more.

here is one simple example. Type this in the test tab of postman.

```
var contentTypeHeaderExists = responseHeaders.hasOwnProperty("Content-Type");

tests["Has Content-Type"] = contentTypeHeaderExists;

if (contentTypeHeaderExists) {
    tests["Content-Type is application/json"] = 
      responseHeaders["Content-Type"].has("application/json");
}
```

Advanced use cases includes grouping and saving different types of APIs by their modules types.

for more details check this [blog](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/)

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the external libraries out there to `automate` the `REST APIS`. Below are few of them you can use:-

1. [REST Assured Library](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured)
2. [HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Once you are done with the API Automation using external libraries you can club the same with `Selenium` to develop `Integration Tests` which will perform some work on `FrontEnd` using `Selenium` library and it can also perform some `Backend` work using any of the aforesaid clients.